# Split string then insert new values into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a migration script to take one column of comma separated values and insert them individually into a new table in SQL server.

The current column is a list of email addresses and I am creating a new table to hold the collection of email addresses for each company.

I would assume I need to first split the string and then run through and INSERT statement for each entry in the array.

Maybe something like this...?

```
SELECT Id,  value
FROM Companies  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Email, ',')

INSERT INTO emailAddresses(emailAddress, companyId)
VALUES (value, Id)
```

But I don't know how to keep the INSERT statement running for all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert...select`.
First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE Companies  (
  Id int identity(1,1),
  Email nvarchar(4000)
);

INSERT INTO Companies(Email) VALUES
('A@gmail.com,B@gmail.com,C@gmail.com'),
('D@gmail.com,E@gmail.com,F@gmail.com'),
('G@gmail.com,H@gmail.com,I@gmail.com');

-- Target table
CREATE TABLE emailAddresses(
  emailAddress nvarchar(1000), 
  companyId int
);
```

Then, the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO emailAddresses(emailAddress, companyId) 
SELECT value, Id
FROM Companies  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Email, ',');
```

A quick select to see the results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM emailAddresses
```

Results:

```
emailAddress    companyId
A@gmail.com     1
B@gmail.com     1
C@gmail.com     1
D@gmail.com     2
E@gmail.com     2
F@gmail.com     2
G@gmail.com     3
H@gmail.com     3
I@gmail.com     3
```

See a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/qgRqP-4w)

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice for future questions.